# Nativescript + Angular 2 - Android - http

Tags: android, angular

I have this code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import observableArrayModule = require("data/observable-array");

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
        <GridLayout>
        <ListView [items]="roomsList" class="small-spacing">
            <template let-item="item">
            <Label [text]="item.numer" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
            </template>
        </ListView>
        </GridLayout>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  //roomsList: Array<Object> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
        //this.roomsList.push({ numer: 1 });
        var http = require("http");
        http.getJSON("http://www.cos.com/query").then(function(result) {

        var count = Object.keys(result).length;
        var roomsList = new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray([]);

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                console.log(result[i].numer);
                //this.roomsList.push({ numer: result[i].numer });
            }

        }, function(error) {});
  }
}
```

How can i list this items from getJSON to ListView. When i use this code outside "for, its working good":

```
roomsList: Array<Object> = [];
this.roomsList.push({ numer: 1 });
```

But this one in "for"

```
this.roomsList.push({ numer: result[i].numer });
```

dont work.

My json data:

```
[{"id":"24","numer":"M51","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"23","numer":"M50","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"19","numer":"M46","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"18","numer":"M18","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"15","numer":"M15","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"124","numer":"M88","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"119","numer":"M44","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"120","numer":"M45","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"125","numer":"M89","status":"1","lang":"pl"},{"id":"126","numer":"M90","status":"1","lang":"pl"}]
```

console.log from "for"

```
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.apka3 on device emulator-5554.
JS: Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
JS: M51
JS: M50
JS: M46
JS: M18
JS: M15
JS: M88
JS: M44
JS: M45
JS: M89
JS: M90
```

Another problem is when i use this.http.get i got "getCookie" error.

Comment: Ok i know what is a problem. `this.roomsList.push` in `http.getJSON` is not working. So how push result outside `http.getJSON` ?